I dont see any files or folders in shinyFiles
I work on a Shiny app to automate some processes for my colleagues. Therefore, they have to choose a folder with their data. As Shiny does not have an build in function to choose folders, I tried to use the shinyFiles package.
#in my UI
shinyDirButton("folder", "Choose folder", "Choose folder", session = F)

#in my server part
shinyDirChoose(input, "folder", roots=c('wd' = '.'))

If I click on the button, I end up with empty "Directories" and "Content" windows and no possibility to navigate to another folder. I work in a Windows environment. Can someone explain me the parameters to start e.g. on my desktop? I have already tried to modify "defaultRoot" and "defaultPath", but I dont understand how?
Thank you for your help in advance,
Anton
